# Need help wtih AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

We have a requirement for our project to listen to queues hosted in different machines. For example, we have 4 virtual hosts. I have created new instance of SimpleMessageListenerContainer for each hosts but i use one instance of MessageListener(it implements ChannelAwareListener so that i can manually ack). MessageListener is a bean managed by spring. I maintain a map of host and container instance when i create the containers. On receiving the message, check if i received the desired message from the host, get the container instance from the map (using @Resource) and stop listening to the host. Also manually ACK and store the message in the cassandra database.

Right now, there are times when some of the messages dont get persisted in the database and gets lost. I think it might be a race condition or due to the fact that i am using only one instance of messagelistener but i had to do that so that i can get the map(@Resource). Sorry if I am not making any sense. I am using the AMQP for the first time and trying to understand it. Any suggestions will be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need manual ack? It's generally better to let the container take care of acks (`AUTO`). It will ack the message on success and nack it if the listener throws an exception.

Comment: We want to process the message and then ACK because if the server goes down, we will loose the message.

Comment: The container will take care of that for you; Spring AMQP `AUTO` ack means the container will ack for normal listener completion and reject (requeue by default) if the listener throws an exception (the messages will also be requeued if the server goes down). This is different to RabbitMQ `autoAck`, which is called `NONE` in Spring AMQP. It is rare to need to use `MANUAL` acks.